# Python equivalent of R list()

Tags: r, python-3.x

R's list() allow labelled elements as well, is there an equivalent way in Python to achieve the following?

```
list("prob", "topTalent", name="Roger")
```

Comment: A dictionary? There is no direct equivalent. Obviously you can roll your own class to have something which is a better match, though it seems like a possible XY problem to do so.

Comment: Using an object or a dictionary

Comment: ordereddict is the closest data structure.

Comment: One way to approach your question: what do pandas equivalents to R functions which return a list return? The pandas `statsmodels.ols()` seems to be a reasonably close match to R's `lm()`, and it returns a custom object rather than something which is a built-in Python data structure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Python documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html implies that you can create recursive structures (the proper R term for structures that can have a tree-characteristic) of varying types with the "[" operator:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> n = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x = [a, n]
>>> x
[['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I'm just an R guy but that would seem to imply that Python's "list" data-type strongly resembles R's list type.

To get named "recursive" structures, it appears one needs to use a "dictionary" ( created with flanking "{","}" ).

```
>>> x = {'a':a, 'n':n}
>>> x
{'a': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'n': [1, 2, 3]}
```

It appears that Python requires names for its dictionary entries while R allows both named and unnamed entries in a list.

```
>>> x = {'a':a, 'n':n, 'z':[1,2,3], 'zz':{'s':[4,5,6], 'd':['t','y']} }
>>> x
{'a': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'n': [1, 2, 3], 'z': [1, 2, 3], 'zz': {'s': [4, 5, 6], 'd': ['t', 'y']}}
```

The accession from Python dicts resembles the access to items when using R:

```
>>> x['zz']
{'s': [4, 5, 6], 'd': ['t', 'y']}
>>> x['zz']['s']
[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: As a someone who mostly programs in Python but sometimes dabbles in R, most of the times that I have created named lists in R, I find myself wishing that R had built-in hash tables. A dictionary is the natural Python equivalent if you wanted to have something named. On the other hand, you are correct that (other than the part about names) Python and R lists are semantically somewhat close to each other. I'm not really sure why your answer got downvoted. It is a good answer (+1) to a somewhat vague question.

Comment: I'm not too bothered about unexplained downvotes these days. If a good explanation is included I'd certainly consider the point of view. I've seen similar requests from other pythonistas and named vectors in R have come the closest. The storage of named character vectors is hashed.

Comment: It's a bit esoteric, but environments in R are basically hash maps. See bottom of http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html, which also includes a reference to [the `hash` packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/index.html) that fully expands on this concept.

Answer (score 5):

There's no equivalent. Python lists have nothing like R's `names`, and OrderedDict (as suggested in the comments) does not allow the equivalent of unnamed elements or duplicate names, as well as not supporting access by element position.

A dict would be the most common way of associating objects with names in Python, but it's still very different from an R list with names. You could certainly create your own class attempting to mimic the equivalent R data structure, perhaps subclassing `list` or `collections.UserList`, but you'd have to implement a lot of functionality yourself, and existing functions you pass your object to wouldn't know what to do with the names.